# Composer и github; скачал либы - залил на гитхаб - в папках ничего нет, как быть?

Tags: git, composer, github

После установки репозиториев в проект залил все на github, а там вместо исходников библиотек или ссылок на них ничего нет. 
То что исходники не должны дублироваться на гитхабе - это понятно. 
Но, если выкачивать проект локально на комп, то он эти либы не выкачивает и весь код не работает.
Что надо сделать, чтобы именно на локалку выкачивались все либы из composer.json сами, при скачивании проекта с гитхаба?

Answer (score 1):

После закачки проекта, нужно выполнить

php composer.phar install
или
php composer.phar update

Например в Symfony2 папка vendor в git не добавляется, её содержимое управляется как раз таки composer'ом.

т.е. весь процесс таков

Клонируем проект с гита

git clone git@example.git

и потом загружаем либы

php composer.phar update